# What will be the possible output?

Tags: c, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I code from a long time but I was never asked questions like this before.

```
main()
{
    int a=5, b, c;
    b=a=15;
    c=a<15;
    printf("%d %d",a,c);
    }
```

What will be the values of a and c? How do we interpret '<' or '>' ?

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: **UB**: no prototype in scope for `printf()` --- anything can happen

Comment: I tried it and it prints c=0. why?

Comment: because, if a is 15, it can't be less than 15, you know.....

Comment: Of course there should be a prototype for printf(); I just didnt write it.

Comment: there is a statement after a=15 and it is a<15(now a is not equal to 15, it is less than 15?)isnt it this?

Comment: Why is c = 0? Is it just a garbage value?

Comment: Exactly! Thanks man. It worked

Comment: @Legionar: the relational operators in C yield `0` or `1` of type `int`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, its already int.

Answer (score 3):

The `<` operator yields `0` or `1` of type `int`.

It yields `1` if its left operand is less than its right operand, `0` otherwise.

In your case the left operand has the value `a` or `15`; the right operand has the value `15`. So the operator yields the value `0`.

Then that `0` is assigned to `c`.

Your statement with extra whitespace, parenthesis, and a comment can be written as

```
c = (a < 15); // assign 0 or 1 to c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main()
{
  int a=5, b, c;
  b=a=15;                  // a = 15
  c=a<15;                  // a is not < 15, a is 15, so c is 0
  printf("%d %d",a,c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the result of this code is undefined, since you do not supply a function prototype for `printf`

Second of all, using `main()` is further undefined since a function needs a return type and `main()` in particular needs to be int return type (handling of other implementations is implementation-defined.

Now assuming you correct your code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a=5, b, c;
    b=a=15;
    c=a<15;
    printf("%d %d",a,c);
    return 0;
    }
```

Then the output for `c` is `0`.

This is because the `<` operator returns int type `0` or `1` based on if the comparison is true.